# Does Xcode have intellisense

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am just waiting for my MacBook to arrive - so at the moment just doing theory, but does Xcode have intellisense like Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called `Code Sense` in Xcode terms.

Have a look at the `Code Completion` section of the [Xcode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/100-The_Text_Editor/text_editor.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's similar - some say not as good, but it works for me - it's called `Code Sense` in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. XCode does have code completion a.k.a. intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, works pretty well.

Comment: So for example if I typed NSLog([myObject

It would immediately pop up with description amongst other class methods?

Comment: It's not the same as Visual Studio, but you can get method/property completion and suggestions, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It does, and it works better than intellisense in my opinion.

I tend to do a lot of work in C++, for which intellisense is worse than useless.

Comment: Did you try VS2010 yet? I saw claims of vast improvements in C++ IS.

Comment: Ah. I've been working with VS 2008 pro. Perhaps I should try out VC++ 2010 Express ;)

Comment: <snark>
I've heard that in VC++ 2011 it's going to be EVEN BETTER. 
</snark>